# ./dkms-install.sh: command not found when installing rtl8812au driver

Tags: command-line, wireless, 20.04, dkms

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/184118), which says:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

My problem is that I get:

```
./dkms-install.sh: command not found
```

Do you know where the problem is?

Answer (score 5):

This instruction is obsolete.

Instead of

```
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

run

```
sudo make dkms_install
```

[Source](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au)